# MySQL and Python -- Int() adding "L"

Tags: python, mysql

I am new to MySQL and I am trying to just test out python and MySQLdb. I was able to create a table in MySQL and print the contents in python.

```
TABLE:
name_number int(11) NO  PRI     
name    varchar(45) YES         

1   Bob
2   steve

Python Output:
(1L, 'Bob')
(2L, 'steve')
```

My Question is where is the "L" coming from? Sorry I know this is a stupid mistake, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: L is for Long, the size of the int.

Comment: Can I have them show just the number of 1?

Comment: @Dumbkid_trying Let's say `row` is your row tuple. If you use `print (', '.join (str(x) for x in row) )`, the L won't show.

Comment: Show us the code that produces the "Python Output" and we'll show you how to fix it.